# Working with my credit card company, daily charges API

Tags: web-services

I want to build an app that, for personal use and fun, that monitors my credit card transactions daily, and sends me a text based on the transaction.

Exactly what I am doing is not important, I'm asking how to get started to see if my credit card company has a service that would allow me to build an application that would get my daily transactions.

The application would monitor my transactions, via their service, and I would consume the info do what I need to do.
Any help in pushing me in the right direction to see if my credit card company has a service that I could use?

Comment: No, don't know where to start, I'm assuming the regular customer service rep would have no idea what I'm talking about

Comment: To be honest with it being such sensitive data they probably wouldn't open up those APIs to you.

Comment: That's a long shot - no way they gonna expose an API for querying credit-card transactions. If it was possible, it would have been a gold mine for agencies that collect information about purchasing habits...

Comment: Banks do have API's available for corporates to automatically download their bank statements, whereby they can automatically reconcile with their internal software, however, the banks tend to be religious with these api's, requiring mutual SSL certificates and naturally, a huge service fee.

Comment: Forget about this. Way too sensitive data.